# It is possible to add the second right axis to dojo chart?

Tags: charts, dojo, axis

I need three axis: One on left, and other on right.

Is it possible to add the second right axis to **dojo** chart?  I did the following, but the right 2 axis overlapped.

```
chart1.addAxis("py", {
    vertical : true,
    fixLower : "major",
    fixUpper : "major",
    includeZero : true,
    leftBottom : false,
    majorTickStep : Math.round(rateMax * 100) / 1000,
    max : rateMax + 5 * rateMax / 100,
    title : isTput?"Mins":"Rate(%)"
}).addPlot("RatePlot", {
    type : "Default",
    vAxis : "py",
    tension : "X",
    markers : true,
    stroke : {
        color : "yellow"
    },
    fill : "yellow",
    animate : true
});

chart1.addAxis("py2", {
    vertical : true,
    fixLower : "major",
    fixUpper : "major",
    includeZero : true,
    leftBottom : false,
    //majorTickStep : Math.round(rateMax * 100) / 1000,
    //max : rateMax + 5 * rateMax / 100,
    title : "Den"
}).addPlot("DenPlot", {
    type : "Default",
    vAxis : "py2",
    tension : "X",
    markers : true,
    stroke : {
        color : "yellow"
    },
    fill : "yellow",
    animate : true
});
```

Comment: you can add other side of X Axis but i don't to possible to add more then one axis is the same side.

Answer (score 0):

Add new html and set the proper location next to the graph axis using style:

```
<div id="xlabel2" style="position: absolute; top: 460px; left: 70px;">Label 2</dev>
```

Turn is on or off as needed using javascript:

```
style: display:none;
       display:visible;
```